# JavaScript SetInterval - Pass function pointer instead of String

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
XService.start = function() {
  setInterval("XService.poll()", XService.pollInterval); }
```

This works great. However, when I do this (passing function as reference instead of having the string eval'd) it stops working:

```
XService.start = function() {
  setInterval(XService.poll, XService.pollInterval); }
```

Why? What am I doing wrong? Nothing else changes in my code. I also tried XService.poll() in the second version but no dice either. The documentation I read said leave the () out.

Help?

Edit: XService.poll is a function; XService.pollInterval is a number. Both are declared and assigned correctly.

Edit2: The XService code:

```
XService = {};
XService.pollUrl = "/Poll";
XService.pollInterval = 60000;
XService.poll = function() {
  $.get(this.pollUrl, null, null, "text"); }
XService.start = function() {
  setInterval(XService.poll, XService.pollInterval); }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is XService.poll a 'function' and 'XService.pollInterval' a number at that specific time?

Edit: Since you posted the code just now..

```
setInterval(

    function() {
        XService.poll();
    }, XService.pollInterval

);
```

Comment: Can we see the whole code for XService? It may have to do with the way it's being defined and in regards to realtime/runtime behaviors and how eval is executed differently.

Answer (score 0):

What the function is bound to changes.

When you call the first, your 'this' statement is bound to XService object.
When you call the second, your 'this' statement is bound to the window object.

for example, say we have XService with poll like this

```
function poll(){ alert(this); }
```

if the first example, it will alert the XService object, but in the second example it will alert the window object.

I don't know the syntax except for in mootools, but in mootoos you would call

```
setInterval(XService.poll.bind(XService), 100)
```

and it would call the method correctly

Comment: Ahhhhh the this statement in the poll function is the culprit then I guess!

Comment: Doing what CMS said will work and will fix the binding issues (using an anonymous function)